# Python: match two list of dictionaries by key and merge matched dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, intersection

Having two lists of dictionaries like

```
big = [{'id': 1234, 'name': 'ipod'}, {'id': 1235, 'name': 'ipod x'}, {'id': 1236, 'name': 'ipod touch'}]

small = [{'id': 1236, 'url': 'directUrl1'}, {'id': 1235, 'url': 'directUrl2'}]
```

I'd like to implement efficient & pythonic way to find intersections between two lists(based on `id`) and create new list of merged dicts:

```
res = [{'id': 1236, 'url': 'directUrl1', 'name': 'ipod touch'}, {'id': 1235, 'url': 'directUrl2', 'name': 'ipod x'}]
```

My current approach:

```
>>> res = []
>>>
>>> for item in [x for x in small if x['id'] in [y['id'] for y in big]]:
...  res.append({**item, **[x for x in big if x['id'] == item['id']][0]})
...
>>> res
[{'id': 1236, 'url': 'directUrl1', 'name': 'ipod touch'}, {'id': 1235, 'url': 'directUrl2', 'name': 'ipod x'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pythonic doesn't mean dense ;)

How about:

```
new_dictlist = []
for d1 in small:
    for d2 in big:
        if d1['id'] == d2['id']:
            new_dictlist.append({'id':d1['id'], 'url':d1['url'], 'name':d2['name']})
```

Or one-liner:

```
[{**x, **y} for x in big for y in small if x['id'] == y['id']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping for `big` that maps `id` with `name`. After that, you can iterate over the `small` list and build the new list of dictionaries.

```
>>> big_map = {d['id']:d['name'] for d in big}
>>> res = [{'id': d['id'], 'url':d['url'], 'name':big_map[d['id']]} for d in small if d['id'] in big_map]
>>> res
[{'id': 1236, 'url': 'directUrl1', 'name': 'ipod touch'}, {'id': 1235, 'url': 'directUrl2', 'name': 'ipod x'}]
```